# The output for some of the inputs should be ‘Wrong number’ but I am not getting that input. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, list

**I copied and pasted the problem below. I am learning python on SoloLearn. The problem runs 5 tests and I got 2 wrong, the ones where the output should be ‘Wrong number’. I cannot see where I went wrong. Please help.**

Imagine a vending machine that sells fruits. Each fruit has its own number, starting from 0.

Write a program for the vending machine, which will take n number as input from the customer and return the fruit with that index.

If n< 0 or  n>7 (the index of last fruit ), program outputs "Wrong number".

CODE:

```
fruits = ["apple", "cherry", "banana", "kiwi", "lemon", "pear", "peach", "avocado"]
num = int(input())
#your code goes here

print(fruits[num])
if num<0 and num>7:
   print('Wrong number')
```

Comment: It should be `or` not `and`

Answer (score 1):

**Corrections:**

1. there should be `or` not `and`
2. print the fruit if the index is right one. If you don't it will give you `list out of index` error.

---

```
fruits = ["apple", "cherry", "banana", "kiwi", "lemon", "pear", "peach", "avocado"]
num = int(input())
#your code goes here

if num<0 or num>7: #<--- here
   print('Wrong number')
else:  # <- added this
    print(fruits[num])
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code for your issue:

```
if num < 0 or num >= len(fruits):
    print('Wrong number')

else:
    print(fruits[num])
```

When you use `len()` instead of 7 you are saying to run the code if the input is greater than or equal to the available objects in the list. This will prevent from any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little bit out of order.
Remember - there are two options. Either the number isn't within 0 and 7 (in which case you'll print 'wrong number'), or the number **is** within 0 and 7 and so you'll print the corresponding fruit.

```
fruits = ["apple", "cherry", "banana", "kiwi", "lemon", "pear", "peach", "avocado"]
num = int(input())

if num<0 and num>7:
   print('Wrong number')
else:
   print(fruits[num])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fruits = ["apple", "cherry", "banana", "kiwi", "lemon", "pear", "peach", "avocado"]

num = int(input())

#your code goes here

if num<0 and num>7:

    print('Wrong number')

else:

    print(fruits[num])
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
fruits = ["apple", "cherry", "banana", "kiwi", "lemon", "pear", "peach", "avocado"]

num = int(input())

#your code goes here

if num>= 0 and num<= len(fruits):
    print(fruits[num])
else:
    print('Wrong number')
```